# DT::renderTable shiny validate

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to validate a shiny datatable. However the validate statement below does not seem to work ???? What´s wrong

```
output$tablepermanovapw <- DT::renderDataTable(

      validate(
        need(values$pwsummarydisplay ==1 , "Need at least 1 row")),

      DT::datatable(values$pw) %>% formatStyle(
      names(values$pw),
      filter = 'top',
      backgroundColor = styleInterval(0.05, c('orange','white'))
    ))
```

The output is as follows when the table contains at least one row. If the table is empty the message is returned properly.

```
Warning: Error in &&: invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

Note that is i remove the validate statement it works, meaning when the table is returned it is rendered. If no table is returned then no table is shown. However i would like to incorporate the validation message.

Comment: Hi. Please include your code or a minimalistic and reprodocable example of your code and data. Otherwise you will have a tough time finding answers.

Comment: or atleast explain how `values$pwsummarydisplay`is calculated...

Comment: ``values$pwsummarydisplay`` is a reactiveValue that is filled with 1 when the table exists in a previous calculation. So if the table exists it is 1 and if the table does not exists it returns 0.

Comment: I think DT::renderDatTable does not handle validate properly !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was a problem with missing brackets and extra commas.... the code aboves works ....

```
output$tablepermanovapw <- DT::renderDataTable({



         validate(
            need(values$pwsummarydisplay ==1 , "Need at least 1 row"))

          DT::datatable(values$pw) %>% formatStyle(
          names(values$pw),
          filter = 'top',
          backgroundColor = styleInterval(0.05, c('orange','white')))
        )
    })
```